Lenovo RD650 fails to start
Have a Lenovo Thinkserver RD650 which was working fine, then got left off for six months and now refuses to start.  Nothing from front power switch, also will not start from TSM.  Both power supplies have correct green lights on.
Is this likely to be a faulty motherboard, is there any way to short out the signal wire somewhere to force it to boot?  Would like to be certain it is the motherboard before replacing it at almost £700.
